# What's the best FFMPEG Minterpolate settings for animation?

Tags: ffmpeg

So, I've been searching for minterpolate settings that fit best, or is the closest to DAIN, but I can't really find some that fit best to how DAIN works.
Usually, this is the minterpolate code I use:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp4 -filter:v "minterpolate='mi_mode=mci:mc_mode=aobmc:vsbmc=1:fps=120:me=fss'" outputfile.mp4
```

I've searched again and again multiple times, but my search just keeps coming back to this line of code being the best settings for what's I'm looking for.
But, does anybody here have any better suggestions for ones that look closest to DAIN, or is the best settings for animation?
Thanks!